# URL redirecting while replaying in loadrunner

Tags: http-status-code-302

I have recorded my application and made all customizations and also working as per the functionality. Now my question is i am looking at snapshot ->split->recording & replaying . while recording response code is coming as 200, but while replay response code is coming as 302. Is this fine? if yes, why it is coming...

Waiting for your valuable answers.

Regards,
Teja

Answer (score 0):

Look at your application logs. A 301 or 302 will eventually resolve to target as a redirect.  You may not "see it" in your browser as this happens transparent to the user.

Look at your generation log.  Search for 302.  If it happened during recording then you will likely see it in the generation log.

Next issue, what if it is not in the HTTP access log on the server and it is not in the recording log, but you still have a redirect?  This likelihood is high that you have missed a dynamic component related to session, state, time, etc... and the system rather than returning a valid page is redirecting you to someplace else for invalid data.